# How to make the console log displayed on the Toggle Developer Tools in Visual Studio Code automatically after saving the JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code version 1.41.1, Live Server 5.6.1
I opened the Toggle Developer Tools from Visual Studio Code \ Help menu, then wrote some JavaScript code and console log, and expected that the variable results displayed on the Toggle Developer Tools automatically but it only displayed something like :[Extension Host] Change detected..." (refer to the attached screenshot: [image: Screenshot]
Anyone can tell me how to make the variable result displayed on the Toggle Developer Tools automatically after saving changes on my JavaScript file?

Thanks